# Google Analytics: How can I differentiate between users that have signed up and not?

Tags: google-analytics

It would be tremendously useful to differentiate between traffic from folks that have an account on my site and signed in, vs. have no account yet. How do I do this in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Populate one of the custom variable and that use that in an advanced segment.

You can populate a custom variable through JS:

`_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'loggedin', 'yes', 2]);`

And then create an advanced segment in Profile > Advanced Segments > "New Segment"

- Include Custom Variable (Key 1) / exactly matching = "yes"

Comment: Custom Fields are not the same as Custom Variables. Filtering based on Custom Variables is not possible yet.